# How to Connect to the Oracle DB using VBscript

Tags: oracle, vbscript

So far I have the following code

```
Dim strConnect
Dim adoConnection
Dim adoRecordset
Dim strSQL
Dim strResults
strSQL = "SELECT COUNT(distinct party_id) FROM apps.per_all_people_f"
strConnect = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1; Password=pwd; Persist Security Info=True; User      ID=user; Data Source=source; Extended Properties="""
Set adoConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
adoConnection.Open strConnect
Set adoRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
adoRecordset.ActiveConnection = adoConnection 
adoRecordset.Source = strSQL
adoRecordset.Open
Do Until adoRecordset.EOF
        strResults = adoRecordset.Fields(0).Value
        msgbox strResults
        adoRecordset.MoveNext
Loop

adoRecordset.Close
adoConnection.Close
```

Help me on correcting above code where I need to connect to Oracle DB and process some steps based on out data.

Im getting following error message.

Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with another. Line 9 Source: ADODB.Connection

Comment: The string `strConnect` looks like it is quoted wrong. It has 2 trailing double quotes at the end. Is that intentional? You can always use `chr(43)` in place of `"` to help make the code readable .

Comment: Tried removing Extended Properties="" Im getting a different message. "Provider cannot be found. It may not properly installed." Code: 800A07A.   But I have already installed the ODAC client and configured the OraTNA  file as well.  The same connection worked when configuring a refreshable sheet in Excel.   Any thoughts?

Comment: How about this `"Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1; Password=pwd; Persist Security Info=True; User      ID=user; Data Source=source; Extended Properties=" & chr(34) & chr(34)`

Comment: If you've installed ODAC, be careful with architectures. Did you install the 32bit or 64bit ODAC? And also, when you double-click your script, does it run in the 32bit or 64bit script host? A script running in the 64bit host won't see registered 32bit libraries.

Comment: Why are there spaces in `User     ID` in the line of `strConnect`? Is it a typo?

Comment: @Jobbo: Verified the ODAC version it is correct. I can create refreshable reports through Excel using ODAC current version.

Comment: @Rachcha: I got it from the excel data connection string. I hope this way it should work.

Answer (score 0):

This is for your information, please correct me if I am wrong:

Ways of connecting to DB:

1. Check ODBC driver is available.
2. If yes, create DSN(System DSN) in the adminstration tools in control panel.
3. Use the code:
   Set con=createobject("adodb.connection")
   con.open "DSN=''"
4. Execute the query

---

1. Check ODBC driver is available.
2. If not able to do DSN then
   Go to environmental variable and then Set Path=""
3. Use the code:
   Set con=createobject("adodb.connection") or 
   Set con=createobject("oledb.connection")
   con.open "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};Server=; Uid=your_username;Pwd=your_password;"
4. Execute Query

Hope this helps. Correct me guys if I am wrong anywhere, as I am still learning.